# how to make the functions thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have a class say `Graph`

```
class Graph
{
    bool* visited;
    void myfun ()
    {
        visited = new bool[10];
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            visited[i]=false;

            myfunc2 ();
    }
    void myfunc2 ()
    {
        // Assume this changes the visited array
    }

}
```

**Now if i call the `myfunc ()` in different threads then they would be working independtly and will change the visited array independetly.....this would make things go wrong.....**

How do i deal with things like this while making a graph library of my own...?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29

Comment: Do you want e.g. `visited` to be shared between the threads? Because now it *isn't*, since you allocate dynamically in each new call to `myfun` each thread calling the function will have a separate `visited` array.

Comment: i dont want  `visited` to be shared....but now if some threads is using the function g.myfunc () and then i call g.myfunc () using the same object in another thread then what will happen...?

Comment: Since there is no resource sharing it will be just fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your threads has an own instance of "Graph", then you do not need thread safety because each thread accesses a different memory area.

But if you share the array between multiple threads:

Use locking (mutex, semaphore), synchronisation or inter-thread communication.

Lock the visited array, eg. std::lock, boost::mutex (or platform specific locking like pthread mutex). And try to lock the data, not the code.

```
somelock.lock();
visited[i]=false; //global array
somelock.unlock();
```